# C++ Playing Sound causes Lag

Tags: c++, audio, wav

For my Zombie Shooter game, I am able to play a sound when the player shoots. It does not stop the entire game, but it creates a 0.5 lag which kind of ruins the game because the zombies are always moving. In a brief form, when I shoot I get a 0.5 second lag. Is their any way I could fix this 0.5 second lag? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib , "winmm.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("Background Music.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised this would give you any lag, as it's certainly not supposed to. Still, it's WinAPI, so I believe you. Ideally you'd use a proper audio library. I always rather liked OpenAL.

Comment: How large is your WAV file?

Comment: How would I be able to use OpenAl? The lag is not big, but somewhere I read that somebody loads the sound file and then plays it at the second spot and it shouldn't cause lag. I don't know if thats true, nor how to do it.

Comment: My WAV File is around one second long. It is just a gun shot for my game.

Comment: As a speed booster, you could add the sound to resources, and play it with SND_RESOURCE flag. ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712876(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: I did not ask how long it lasts!

Comment: _"How would I be able to use OpenAl?"_ By visiting the website and reading the documentation. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I just changed my name so sorry for any confusion, but the file is 19KB.

Comment: @Frederik.L, for some reason I have some text in red. Do I have to include a header?

Comment: @SirRyan I would use OpenAL along with OggVorbis!